# how can i get the total to display dynamically after a form is filled

Tags: javascript

the following is a javascript to calculate a total from a filled form ... how can i display the total after the required fields are filled

```
  var price;
  var aclevel=parseInt(document.getElementById("aclev"));
  var paperugency=document.getElementById("paperurgency");
  var pages=parseInt(document.getElementById("papernos"));
  var papertype=document.getElementById("papertype");
  var total = "$" + (price * pages).toFixed(2);
 //the total is to be displyed in a text fields dynamically
document.getElementById('total').value=total;
 //part of the form i want to display the total
 <p>Total</p> <input type="text" id="total">
```

Comment: have your considered angular? It will be way much simpler

Comment: Use a change event binder, do you use jQuery ? You can get it easily.
When a change is done, you check the fields, if the required are filled, you display the total.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the `onchange` attribute. This attribute receives a function and executes it each time the corresponding event occurs.

You may also other event attributes, such as `onblur`, `onfocus`, `onkeyup`, `onkeypress`, `onkeydown` etc., and you can even use them in combination.

```
// what to do when fields get changed
var onchangefn = function(){

    // get the values
    var aclevel=parseInt(document.getElementById("aclev").value);
    var paperugency=document.getElementById("paperurgency").value;
    var pages=parseInt(document.getElementById("papernos").value);
    var papertype=document.getElementById("papertype").value;

    // calculate total
    var total = "$" + (price * pages).toFixed(2);

    // check to see if total was calculated correctly using the values above
    total = isNaN(total) ? "" : total;

    document.getElementById('total').value=total;
}

// dynamically attach onchangefn to the fields
var fields = ['aclev','paperurgency','papernos','papertype'];

for(var i in fields){

    // triggers when field value changes, and most likely gets defocused
    document.getElementById(fields[i]).onchange = function(){ onchangefn(); } 

    // triggers when a key is pressed and the field is focused
    document.getElementById(fields[i]).onkeydown = function(){ onchangefn(); } 

}
```

Comment: i have a couple of if statements before the calculate total that determine the price ....

Comment: @user3720366 put them before `// check to see if total was calculated correctly using the values above` in the `onchangefn()` function.

Comment: what a button to calculate the total since it seams not to work in my case

Comment: @user3720366 `<button type="button" onclick="onchangefn()">Calculate</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `value` to get the value of field

```
var price;
var aclevel = parseInt(document.getElementById("aclev").value);
var paperugency = document.getElementById("paperurgency").value;
var pages = parseInt(document.getElementById("papernos").value);
var papertype = document.getElementById("papertype").value;
var total = "$" + (price * pages).toFixed(2);

//the total is to be displyed in a text fields dynamically
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
//part of the form i want to display the total
<p>Total</p> <input type="text" id="total">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a javascript function (this is a jQuery version, you may transform into pure javascript).  Use this function in onchange event of field1 and field2 input boxes.

```
function CalculateTotal()
{
  var v1 = $('#field1').val();
  var v2 = $('#field2').val();
  //write total into the total field
  $('#total').val(parseDouble(v1) * parseDouble(v2));
}
```

Comment: OP has not tag jQuery, you cant force OP to use jquery

Comment: If you read my response, it says that this code can be transformed into pure JavaScript.  He already has those JavaScript code lines in the original question.  the point here is to use the onchange event to calculate the total.